# Sorting integers in a csv file - python

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
Tom,10
Jack,10
Alice,10
Ben,9
```

I need to be able to sort by the second column from highest to lowest.
I have tried the following code:

```
import csv

file = open("bestscores.csv","r")
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ' ')

sort = sorted(reader,key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)
print(sort)
```

This results in the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Tom,10'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong delimiter and sorting the wrong index. This should work for you:

```
import csv

with open("bestscores.csv","r") as fh
  reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter = ',')

  sort = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)
  print(sort)
```

Comment: You should use with to open a file or at least close it

Comment: you don't need to add `delimiter = ','` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this also,

```
with open('file') as f:
    print(''.join(sorted(f, key=lambda x: int(x.split(',')[1]), reverse=True)))
```

Comment: You can call sorted on the file object