# Sorting csv data by a column of numerical values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a csv file that has 10 columns and about 7,000 rows. I have to sort the data based on the 4th column (0, 1, 2, 3), which I know is column #3 with 0 based counting. The column has a header and the data in this column is numeric values. The largest value in this column is: 7548375288960, so that row should be at the top of my results.

My code is below. Something interesting is happening. If I change the reverse=True to reverse=False then the 15 rows printed to the screen are the correct ones based on me manually sorting the csv file in Excel. But when I set reverse=True they are not the correct ones. Below are the first 4 that my print statement puts out:

999016759.26

9989694.0

99841428.0

998313048.0

Here is my code:

```
def display():
    theFile = open("MyData.csv", "r")
    mycsv = csv.reader(theFile)
    sort = sorted(mycsv, key=operator.itemgetter(3), reverse=True)
    for row in islice(sort, 15):
        print(row)
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you sorting the column as string or a number?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I think that's the problem. I think I'm sorting them as a string, but need to sort them as a number, not sure how to go about that

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181513/sorting-integers-in-a-csv-file-python

Comment: @Mike67, that was very helpful, led me in the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got this solved. A couple of things:

1. The data in the column, while only containing numerical values, was in string format. To overcome this I did the following in the function that was generating the csv file.

   concatDf["ColumnName"] = concatDf["ColumnName"].astype(float)

This converted all of the strings to floats. Then in my display function I changed the sort line of code to the following:

```
sort = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: int(float(x[3])), reverse=True)
```

2. Then I got a different error that I realized was trying to covert the header from string to float and this was impossible. To overcome that I added the following line:

next(theFile, None)

This is what the function looks like now:

```
def display():
    theFile = open("MyData.csv", "r")
    next(theFile, None)
    reader = csv.reader(theFile, delimiter = ",", quotechar='"')
    sort = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: int(float(x[3])), reverse=True)
    for row in islice(sort, 15):
        print(row)
```